# Execcommand insert image into iframe with html input tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, execcommand

I'm working in this wysiwyg and all the examples and tutorial that I saw make a prompt to enter the URL and insert the image, but I wanted to take by the hard way using a html input tag with type="file", until now I have been able to open the dialog and everything but I don't know how to get the URL or path of the chosen img to insert it on the iframe that I'm working (code next).

html:

```
    <input type="file" id="imageop" onchange="iImage(contenido)" value="Image">
    <textarea name="resumentext" id="resumentext" rows="5" cols="50" style="display:none;"></textarea>
    <iframe name="resumen" id="resumen" style="background: white;"></iframe>
```

Javascript

```
function iImage(table){ 
var imgSrc = document.getElementById("unlinkop");

table.document.execCommand('insertimage', false, imgSrc); 


}
```

Does anyone know how can I get the image chosen inserted into the iframe? also, you can just ignore the textarea, I left it there to somehow left explicit that when submitted the iframe is inserted into a textarea and that is posted.